# Find real solutions for p(b)

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

I have a polynomial $p(b)=b^5 -b^4 -3b^3 -7b^2 -5b -3=0$. I don’t know how to solve that. Can somebody please explain how to factorize this step by step?

Comment: By inspection, you find that $3$ is a root. Polynomial division leads to a polynomial which turns out to be equal to $(x^2+x+1)^2$, hence there is no further root.

Comment: Is it possible that  the question is asking  you about possible rational roots? By the rational roots theorem $\pm1,\pm3$ are the only possible rational roots.

Comment: Well, full question is (101010)_b = (10101)_(b+1). When I write that down, I get that equation and I don’t know how to solve it. I know that b can only be bigger than 2, so only solution is 3, but I don’t know how to solve or factorize that polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1,-1,3,-3 does not look right. For example, 1 cannot be a root, just add up the coefficients.   One useful test is looking for repeat factors, find polynomial gcd of your polynomial and its formal derivative over the rationals. The outcome is $x^2 + x + 1,$ meaning that $ x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  - 7 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 3$ is actually divisible by $(x^2 + x + 1)^2 = x^4 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 2x + 1,$ polynomial division gives

$$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  - 7 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 3 \right)  =  \left(   x^{4}  + 2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot   \left(   x  - 3 \right)     $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  - 7 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 3 \right)  = \left(x^2 + x + 1 \right)^2   \cdot   \left(   x  - 3 \right)     $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  - 7 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  - 9 x^{2}  - 14 x  - 5 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  - 7 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 3 \right)  =  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  - 9 x^{2}  - 14 x  - 5 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 5 x  - 1 }{ 25 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 34 x^{3}  - 114 x^{2}  - 114 x  - 80 }{ 25 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  - 9 x^{2}  - 14 x  - 5 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 34 x^{3}  - 114 x^{2}  - 114 x  - 80 }{ 25 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 2125 x  + 8825 }{ 578 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 12675 x^{2}  + 12675 x  + 12675 }{ 289 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{  - 34 x^{3}  - 114 x^{2}  - 114 x  - 80 }{ 25 }  \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 12675 x^{2}  + 12675 x  + 12675 }{ 289 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 9826 x  - 23120 }{ 316875 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 5 x  - 1 }{ 25 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 5 x  - 1 }{ 25 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 2125 x  + 8825 }{ 578 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 425 x^{2}  + 1850 x  + 225 }{ 578 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 2125 x  + 8825 }{ 578 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 9826 x  - 23120 }{ 316875 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 289 x^{3}  - 578 x^{2}  - 578 x  - 867 }{ 12675 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 1445 x^{2}  - 2601 x  - 1445 }{ 12675 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  - 2 x  - 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 85 x  + 353 }{ 1014 }  \right)  -  \left(  5 x^{2}  - 9 x  - 5 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 17 x^{2}  + 74 x  + 9 }{ 1014 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  - 7 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 3 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  - 2 x  - 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  - 9 x^{2}  - 14 x  - 5 \right)  =  \left(  5 x^{2}  - 9 x  - 5 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  - 7 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 85 x  + 353 }{ 1014 }  \right)  -  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  - 9 x^{2}  - 14 x  - 5 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 17 x^{2}  + 74 x  + 9 }{ 1014 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x^{2}  -  x  - 1 \right)  $$

Comment: +1 for the gcd idea. You solved this by hand or using a calculator ? am curious